# Is it possible to rename node from "children" to any other name as per requirement

Tags: json, extjs, tree

Is it possible to rename node from "children" to any other name as per requirement of tree structure in extjs tree. I am using json for tree structure as follows:

```
name: '.',

children: [{
    name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    children:[{
        name:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{
        name:'Accordion',
        id:'accordion',
        leaf:true
    },{
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have made changes in .js file, where I can change

proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.json',   
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                root: 'mydata' \\I change here root: 'mydata'
            },
        },

but i need to change it as per req in structure. i.e mydata1, mydata2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-defaultRootProperty

You could look into mapping and convert properties of the field http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field

I believe you could setup converting of all items you need using them.

Comment: I have tried it, it works. but what if i have 5 different types of root in single json for tree. e.g 'mydata1' 'mydata2' and so on..

Comment: In my case where to add 'mydata1' 'mydata2'. I am new to extjs. it would be great if u could sent me in the proper format.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/FGpFM/ just a pseudo code, not sure if it really works. simple to give you an idea