# Can we rename "Children" node in extjs tree

Tags: extjs, tree

Can we rename the "**children**" node in extjs tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to rename node from "children" to any other name as per requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516099/is-it-possible-to-rename-node-from-children-to-any-other-name-as-per-requireme)

Comment: I had tried it, but in my current situation when i make root: "mydata" and rename the other "children" node. It repeat the header without showing inner content of nodes.

Comment: this is my jason:


mydata: [{
    name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    course:[{
        name:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{

Its not shoiwng content under "course:" , only showing folder "Basic Ext Layouts", and repeat same when i click on it. how to solve?

Comment: can we create the tree in extjs with multiple roots with json?

Comment: I believe the only option for you here is to create your own custom `reader` or override the `read` method of built-in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you transform your data before loading it to tree. Simply loop through your data and replace "your-custom-name" with "children".

A step further is to implement it as a custom reader as Molecule Man suggested.